# How do I solve the first set of clues in Part 1 of Paper Trail?

Tags: infamous-second-son, infamous-paper-trail

I can't make heads or tails of what I'm supposed to do here; I've looked at the origami dove, the crime scene photos, and the detective's wallet, but I can't figure out what Delsin's Phone is supposed to be used for, or where I should even be looking. Help!

Comment: I haven't played *Second Son* yet, but "Paper Trail" looks like a quest to me. Is it really such a complex quest, that it'd need a tag of its own?

Comment: It's a free add-on scenario that includes web-based ARG elements (i.e., they take place entirely out of the game, and require you to examine clues and solve puzzles in a web browser.) It seemed like it deserved a subtag to me, but I'm fine with removing it if I'm in the minority opinion.

Comment: No, that's fine. Since it's not part of the main game, it's earned its own tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since part of the fun of Paper Trail is figuring things out for yourself, I'm going to spoiler-code some things, so people can get only the hints they need. However, some parts of the solution are pretty obscure, so a small nudge in the right direction may be all that many people need, myself included.

1. Examine the wallet, thoroughly. Don't overlook anything you see; it's all of potential importance. Note that some items can be flipped over to examine what's on the reverse side.
2. > Pay particular attention to the detective agency business card.
3. > Pay particular-particular attention to the e-mail address on the business card.
4. > Try opening the domain name "brunbergdetectiveagency.com" in your web browser.
5. > Scroll down and click the "Employees Log In Here" link. Click the "Forgot Password" link on the following page.
6. > All of the clues that you need to log in can be found in the detective's wallet. Remember to check the back of every item.
7. > Once you're logged in, click on the active case and read everything.
8. > Enter the Mobile Device ID into Delsin's Phone on the main Paper Trail site.
9. Start the next leg of the mission in the game!

Comment: I've gone through all of this and entered the ID into Delsin's phone but nothing happens, am I missing something?

Comment: yes you are, you need to find a series of number in a file mine was 12 digits long

Comment: Kudos for your excellent use of the spoiler tag!